# QMessage box to disappear based on IF condition

Tags: qt

I've the following code to display a `QMessageBox` when a sensor is getting disconnected from my serial device

```
   QMessageBox msgBox;
    if (topic==TOPIC_DEVICE)
    {
        switch(reg)
        {
  
        case STIM_REG_NUM_SENSORS:
           if(value==0){                    // if statement to display message box
               msgBox.setText("Sensor got disconnected....");
               msgBox.setWindowTitle(" Sensor.");
               msgBox.exec();
           }
           else if(value==1){
               msgBox.close();
           }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Here the issue, it correctly shows the Message box when the sensor getting disconnected (`if(value==0)`) but I want the message box to disappear automatically when the the sensor is connected back (`if(value==1)`), and I tried as above.

The problem, message box will not desappear until I press the OK button on it.

Is there a way to hide this OK button on the message box and make it disapper autmatically as the condition satisfy (that is `if(value==1)`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that `msgBox.exec();` is blocking in your `switch` statement ( https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec ).

If you use non blocking calls such as `void QDialog::open()` or `void QMessageBox::open(QObject *receiver, const char *member)`, your `QMessageBox` will probably be closed as expected.